# How to compose two different `State Monad`?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state, monads

When I learn `State Monad`, I'm not sure how to compose two functions with different `State` return types.

State Monad definition:

```
case class State[S, A](runState: S => (S, A)) {

  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = {
    State(s => {
      val (s1, a) = runState(s)
      val (s2, b) = f(a).runState(s1)
      (s2, b)
    })
  }

  def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] = {
    flatMap(a => {
      State(s => (s, f(a)))
    })
  }

}
```

Two different State types:

```
type AppendBang[A] = State[Int, A]

type AddOne[A] = State[String, A]
```

Two methods with differnt State return types:

```
def addOne(n: Int): AddOne[Int] = State(s => (s + ".", n + 1))

def appendBang(str: String): AppendBang[String] = State(s => (s + 1, str + " !!!"))
```

Define a function to use the two functions above:

```
def myAction(n: Int) = for {
  a <- addOne(n)
  b <- appendBang(a.toString)
} yield (a, b)
```

And I hope to use it like this:

```
println(myAction(1))
```

The problem is `myAction` is not compilable, it reports some error like this:

```
Error:(14, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : state_monad.State[Int,(Int, String)]
 required: state_monad.State[String,?]
    b <- appendBang(a.toString)
      ^
```

How can I fix it? Do I have to define some Monad transformers?

---

Update: The question may be not clear, let me give an example

Say I want to define another function, which uses `addOne` and `appendBang` internally. Since they all need existing states, I have to pass some to it:

```
def myAction(n: Int)(addOneState: String, appendBangState: Int): ((String, Int), String) = {
  val (addOneState2, n2) = addOne(n).runState(addOneState)
  val (appendBangState2, n3) = appendBang(n2.toString).runState(appendBangState)
  ((addOneState2, appendBangState2), n3)
}
```

I have to run `addOne` and `appendBang` one by one, passing and getting the states and result manually.

Although I found it can return another `State`, the code is not improved much:

```
def myAction(n: Int): State[(String, Int), String] = State {  
case (addOneState: String, appendBangState: Int) =>  
  val (addOneState2, n2) = addOne(n).runState(addOneState)  
  val (appendBangState2, n3) = appendBang(n2.toString).runState(  appendBangState)
    ((addOneState2, appendBangState2), n3)
}
```

Since I'm not quite familiar with them, just wondering is there any way to improve it. The best hope is that I can use `for` comprehension, but not sure if that's possible

Comment: Your `flatMap` function transforms a `State[S, A]` into a `State[S, B]`, so you can not change the type of the state in a for comprehension. How would you even want to go from a `String` to an `Int` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens Thanks, my question is better to be: If in my function, I want to use the two functions which return different State monads, how can I do it? say, how to pass some existing states to it, and how to get them for latter use?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you add an example of how you would like to use the two different `States` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens Just updated, thanks for replies

Comment: @PeterNeyens: He seems to want to lift his two state functions over `A` and `B` to a `State[(A,B), …]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my first comment, it will be impossible to use a for comprehension to do what you want, because it can not change the type of the state (`S`).

Remember that a for comprehension can be translated to a combination of `flatMaps`, `withFilter` and one `map`. If we look at your `State.flatMap`, it takes a function `f` to change a `State[S,A]` into `State[S, B]`. We can use `flatMap` and `map` (and thus a for comprehension) to chain together operations on the same state, but we can't change the type of the state in this chain.

We could generalize your last definition of `myAction` to combine, compose, ... two functions using state of a different type. We can try to implement this generalized compose method directly in our `State` class (although this is probably so specific, it probably doesn't belong in `State`). If we look at `State.flatMap` and `myAction` we can see some similarities:

- We first call `runState` on our existing `State` instance.
- We then call `runState` again

In `myAction` we first use the result `n2` to create a `State[Int, String]` (`AppendBang[String]` or `State[S2, B]`) using the second function (`appendBang` or `f`) on which we then call `runState`. But our result `n2` is of type `String` (`A`) and our function `appendBang` needs an `Int` (`B`) so we need a function to convert `A` into `B`.

```
case class State[S, A](runState: S => (S, A)) {
  // flatMap and map

  def compose[B, S2](f: B => State[S2, B], convert: A => B) : State[(S, S2), B] =
    State( ((s: S, s2: S2) => {
      val (sNext, a) = runState(s)
      val (s2Next, b) = f(convert(a)).runState(s2)
      ((sNext, s2Next), b)
    }).tupled)
}
```

You then could define `myAction` as :

```
def myAction(i: Int) = addOne(i).compose(appendBang, _.toString)

val twoStates = myAction(1)
// State[(String, Int),String] = State(<function1>)

twoStates.runState(("", 1))
// ((String, Int), String) = ((.,2),2 !!!)
```

If you don't want this function in your `State` class you can create it as an external function :

```
def combineStateFunctions[S1, S2, A, B](
  a: A => State[S1, A], 
  b: B => State[S2, B], 
  convert: A => B
)(input: A): State[(S1, S2), B] = State( 
  ((s1: S1, s2: S2) => {
    val (s1Next, temp) = a(input).runState(s1)
    val (s2Next, result) = b(convert(temp)).runState(s2)
    ((s1Next, s2Next), result)
  }).tupled
)

def myAction(i: Int) = 
  combineStateFunctions(addOne, appendBang, (_: Int).toString)(i)
```

Edit : *Bergi*'s idea to create two functions to lift a `State[A, X]` or a `State[B, X]` into a `State[(A, B), X]`.

```
object State {  
  def onFirst[A, B, X](s: State[A, X]): State[(A, B), X] = {
    val runState = (a: A, b: B) => {
      val (nextA, x) = s.runState(a)
      ((nextA, b), x)
    }
    State(runState.tupled)
  }

  def onSecond[A, B, X](s: State[B, X]): State[(A, B), X] = {
    val runState = (a: A, b: B) => {
      val (nextB, x) = s.runState(b)
      ((a, nextB), x)
    }
    State(runState.tupled)
  }
}
```

This way you can use a for comprehension, since the type of the state stays the same (`(A, B)`).

```
def myAction(i: Int) = for {
  x <- State.onFirst(addOne(i))
  y <- State.onSecond(appendBang(x.toString))
} yield y

myAction(1).runState(("", 1))
// ((String, Int), String) = ((.,2),2 !!!)
```

Comment: Hm, would it be possible to use `flatMap` and `for` comprehenions if you did define two "cast" functions `asFirst[A](State[B, X]): State[(A,B), X]` and `asSecond[B](State[A, X]): State[(A,B), X]` (or so)? If yes, what would be the most idiomatic way to do so (I'm not well versed in Scala)?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an implementation of your idea.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess `onFirst` and `onSecond` are more sensible names. It's not that we take the results *as* something, but we operate *on* a part of the state.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, those names seem to be more semantically correct.